# Are there ways to learn and practice Deep Learning without downloading and installing anything?

Tags: deep-learning, architecture

As per subject title, are there ways to try Deep Learning without downloading and installing anything?

I'm just trying to have a feel of how this work, not really want to go through the download and install step if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "try DL"?

Comment: @naive Deep Learning. edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, I think you wish to directly try out some deep learning stuff and things like library downloading, tools downloading, and managing all these really stop you from even starting to try out deep learning experiments.If this is what you asked for:

1. Google Colab

   I think this is the best place for you.
   Anyone with a Google Drive account can sign up for Colab by heading to 
    and following the listed instructions.

   Since you mentioned that you just wanted to try out and practice stuffs, this would be 
   ideal for you.

   - All major Python libraries like TensorFlow, Scikit-learn, Matplotlib among many 
     others 
     are pre-installed and ready to be imported.
   - Built on top of Jupyter Notebook

   Please have a quick look at:

   https://medium.com/lean-in-women-in-tech-india/google-colab-the-beginners-guide-5ad3b417dfa

2.Microsoft Azure

The Azure free account is available to all new customers of Azure. If you have never 
  tried or paid for Azure before, you’re eligible.
  Try out a student account:
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/students/

Hope this helps, go ahead with practicing deep learning 
if not please feel free to raise questions, always ready to help

---

Comment: Thank you! That is what I meant and looking for.

Comment: I am glad, I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely get a good handle on the theory of various concepts in ML(I.e the agent-environment loop and Markov Decision Processes) but true understanding(for the vast majority of people) will only come through application of the aforementioned theory.

I would suggest something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjZBTDzGeGg&t=4s) course to get your feet wet in ML

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Tensorflow playground?  It allows you turn all of the knobs and see the effect without having to code anything
https://playground.tensorflow.org

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting!